# How to include postgresql JAR file to java application using VS code IDE?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jar

I have downloaded jar file and added it to Reference Libraries section in VS code.
[image]

but when I have run below code I am getting exception in 10th and 11th line.

```java
import java.sql.*;;;
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url;
        String user;
        String passWord;
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Demo";
        user = "Postgres";
        passWord = "0000";
        try {Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {System.out.println("Exception in first try - "+e);;}
        try {Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passWord);} catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("Exception in second try "+e);;}
        System.out.println("connection got established");
    }
}
```

Error I am getting -

```
Exception in first try - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
Exception in second try java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Demo
connection got established
```

I have spend lot of time to find cause of this issue, please help me to fix this one.

Comment: Comment out the `Class.forName` line. What happens then?

Comment: In that case I'm getting below output - 
Exception in second try java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Demo
connection got established